# Problem Using SMS and Internet at the same time W Telit UL865 NAD

Tags: sms, apn

I have no problems sending SMS in text mode with the Telit UL865 NAD
Once initialized in Text mode I then try to connect to the APN
with;

```
AT+CGDCONT=1... which responds OK
Then I do a AT#SGACT=1,1 ... which also responds with and IP and OK
Next step AT#HTTPCFG=0, ... to connect to the URL root. Also OK
And finally an AT#HTTPQRY=0,0, .. to GET data, which also works.
```

But now, I can't send SMS anymore.

Do I have to Switch modes independently or deactivate (AT#SGACT=1,0 ..) the APN connectión
before sending SMS.

What is the method used for this?

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved turning off flow control with the AT&K0 command after the AT#SGACT command.

Without it communications hung and wouldn't let the modem continue